# how can i add credentials in New-PSSession? everytime i face the login-prompt (powershell)

Tags: powershell

im trying to schedule a powershellscript which changes the calender permissions of users within the group "kalender_rechten" to limited details. however im facing the login prompt on new-pssesion. how can i add the $credObject  into New-PSSession, without the loginprompt?

```
#Start transcript
Start-Transcript -Path C:\temp\Set-DefCalPermissions.log -Append

 #get credentials to authenticate
 $username = "test.onmicrosoft.com"
 $pwdTxt = Get-Content "C:\test\test\pw.txt"
 $securePwd = $pwdTxt | ConvertTo-SecureString 
 $credObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 
 $username, $securePwd

#authenticate admin office365
get-credential $credObject

#create session Office365
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 
https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $credObject -Authentication 
Basic –AllowRedirection
$credObject

#import Office365/exchange commands to PowerShell console
Import-PSSession $Session

# Get all user mailboxes
$Users = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Kalender_rechten"

 # Permissions
$Permission = "LimitedDetails"

# Calendar name languages
$FolderCalendars = @("Agenda", "Calendar", "Calendrier", "Kalender")

# Loop through each user
foreach ($User in $Users) {

# Get calendar in every user mailbox
$Calendars = (Get-MailboxFolderStatistics $User.Identity -FolderScope Calendar)

    # Loop through each user calendar
    foreach ($Calendar in $Calendars) {
        $CalendarName = $Kalender_rechten

        # Check if calendar exist
        if ($FolderCalendars -Contains $CalendarName) {
            $Cal = $User.Identity.ToString() + ":\$CalendarName"
            $CurrentMailFolderPermission = Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $Cal - User Default
            
            # Set calendar permission / Remove -WhatIf parameter after testing
            Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $Cal -User Default -AccessRights 
  $Permission -WarningAction:SilentlyContinue -WhatIf
            
            # Write output
            if ($CurrentMailFolderPermission.AccessRights -eq "$Permission") {
                Write-Host $User.Identity already has the permission 
 $CurrentMailFolderPermission.AccessRights -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
            else {
                Write-Host $User.Identity added permissions $Permission -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        }
    }
}

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Does `C:\test\test\pw.txt` contain the password in cleartext?

Comment: oh yea i forgot to mention i've made it with a secure string, with the following script:
$username = "test.onmicrosoft.com"
$password = "Password123!"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$secureStringText = $secureStringPwd | ConvertFrom-SecureString 
Set-Content "C:\test\test\pw.txt" $secureStringText

the strange thing is, it does work for:   get-credential $credObject

Comment: Re-importing and/or converting an exported SecureString requires that the security context of the process is the same one that exported it in the first place. So if the script is to be run unattended with the credentials of a service account, then the same service account must run the script that exports the secure string in the first place. Makes sense?

Comment: that makes sense, and thank you for your fast response again. as for testing purposes i've devided it into 2 scripts. both of them were and are executed within the same login service account. i shouldn't matter i'd closed the powershell terminal in between the 2 scripts right? (since its the same service account)

Comment: The only alternative approach that comes to mind is to use `Export/Import-CliXml` instead of `ConvertFrom-SecureString` + `Set-Content`: In the script that stages the credentials, do `[pscredential]::new($username, $secureStringPwd) |Export-CliXml -Path creds.ps1xml`, then in the script that actually does the work: `$credObject = Import-CliXml creds.ps1xml`. Also, make sure that all the arguments to `New-PSSession` are on the same line, it's unclear from your post whether `$credObject` is on a separate line because of formatting or not...

Comment: Hi Mathias, Thank you for your alternative approach. i've managed to fix it, it was a typo... furthermore i rewrote the whole script and it works.